# on foot Vs. on feet

Tags: phrases

> I'm coming home **on foot**?

is equal to

> I'm coming home **on feet**?

I've heard non native speakers mainly say both. I'm not sure if "on feet" is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

The usual expression is [**on foot**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/on_foot) or **by foot**.

> I am coming home on foot.

Similarly with [**by hand**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/by_hand).

> This bread was made by hand.

We use "on feet" in a different context:

> I was on my feet (I was standing).